# Basis of the vector space generated by a convex cone

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a pointed convex cone in a vector space, meaning that:

- $C + C \subset C$,
- $\mathbb{R}_+ \cdot C \subset C$,
- $C \cap (-C) = \{ 0 \}$.

If $V$ denotes the vector space generated by $C$, i.e. $V = C - C$, is it always possible to find a basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ of $V$ such that $e_i \in C$ for all $i$?

Comment: May we assume finite-dimensional?

Comment: Since $V$ is spanned by $C$, you can find a basis of $V$ inside $C$. This holds for any subset $C$, you don't need it to be a cone.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, it suffices to use the incomplete basis theorem.